# Modifying Word Document XML using Packages

Tags: c#, xml, ms-word

I am attempting to modify a simple MS word templates XML. I realize there are SDK's available that could make this process easier but what I am tasked with maintaining uses packages and I was told to do the same.

I have a basic test document with two placeholders mapped to the following XML:

```
<root>
  <element>
     Fubar
  </element>
  <second>
     This is the second placeholder
  </second>
</root>
```

What I am doing is creating a stream using the word doc, removing the existing XML, getting some hard coded test XML and trying to write that to the stream.

Here is the code I am using:

```
string strRelRoot = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument";
byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes("dev.docx");
//stream with the template
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer, true);
//create a package using the stream
Package package = Package.Open(stream, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
PackageRelationshipCollection pkgrcOfficeDocument = package.GetRelationshipsByType(strRelRoot);
foreach (PackageRelationship pkgr in pkgrcOfficeDocument)
{
    if (pkgr.SourceUri.OriginalString == "/")
    {
        Uri uriData = new Uri("/customXML/item1.xml", UriKind.Relative);
        //remove the existing part
        if (package.PartExists(uriData))
        { 
            // Delete template "/customXML/item1.xml" part
            package.DeletePart(uriData);
        }
        //create a new part
        PackagePart pkgprtData = package.CreatePart(uriData, "application/xml");
        //test data
        string xml = @"<root>
                        <element>
                            Changed
                        </element>
                        <second>
                                The second placeholder changed
                        </second>
                    </root>";
        //stream created from the xml string
        MemoryStream fromStream = new MemoryStream();
        UnicodeEncoding uniEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
        byte[] fromBuffer = uniEncoding.GetBytes(xml);
        fromStream.Write(fromBuffer, 0, fromBuffer.Length);
        fromStream.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        Stream toStream = pkgprtData.GetStream();
        //copy the xml to the part stream
        fromStream.CopyTo(toStream);
        //copy part stream to the byte stream
        toStream.CopyTo(stream);

    }
}
```

This is currently not modifying the document although I feel like I am close to a solution. Any advice would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: To clairify, the result I am getting is the document is unchanged. I get no exceptions or the like, but the documents XML is not modified.

Comment: I'll be able to take a look at this in more depth in an hour or two. In the meantime, could you update the question to say what result you _are_ getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so not quite the timely response I promised, but here goes!

There are several aspects to the problem. Sample code is from memory and documentation, not necessarily compiled and tested.

---

### Read the template XML

Before you delete the package part containing the template XML, you need to open its stream and read the XML. How you get the XML if the part doesn't exist to begin with is up to you.

My example code uses classes from the [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) API, though you could use whichever set of XML APIs you prefer.

```
XElement templateXml = null;
using (Stream stream = package.GetPart(uriData))
    templateXml = XElement.Load(stream);
// Now you can delete the part.
```

At this point you have an in-memory representation of the template XML in `templateXml`.

---

### Substitute values into the placeholders

```
templateXml.SetElementValue("element", "Replacement value of first placeholder");
templateXml.SetElementValue("second", "Replacement value of second placeholder");
```

Check out the methods on [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) if you need to do anything more advanced than this, e.g. read the original content in order to determine the replacement value.

---

### Save the document

This is your original code, modified and annotated.

```
// The very first thing to do is create the Package in a using statement.
// This makes sure it's saved and closed when you're done.
using (Package package = Package.Open(...))
{
    // XML reading, substituting etc. goes here.

    // Eventually...
    //create a new part
    PackagePart pkgprtData = package.CreatePart(uriData, "application/xml");
    // Don't need the test data anymore.
    // Assuming you need UnicodeEncoding, set it up like this.
    var writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        Encoding = Encoding.Unicode,
    };
    // Shouldn't need a MemoryStream at all; write straight to the part stream.
    // Note using statements to ensure streams are flushed and closed.
    using (Stream toStream = pkgprtData.GetStream())
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(toStream, writerSettings))
        templateXml.Save(writer);
    // No other copying should be necessary.
    // In particular, your toStream.CopyTo(stream) appeared
    // to be appending the part's data to the package's stream
    // (the physical file), which is a bug.
} // This closes the using statement for the package, which saves the file.
```